# How to monitor for keystrokes pressed when outside the App?

Tags: c#, events, keyboard-shortcuts

I need a way in C# to monitor system-wide keys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, so I can act upon that.

How could I get such an event, even when the keys were pressed with my App no longer in focus?

Comment: for what purpose you want to do this? to look for *Idle* period or to record keys in key logger ;)

Comment: Oops, thought it was exact duplicate, but the other question was Delphi, so not the same, sorry

Comment: Have a look at this link : [Global System Hooks in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx)

Comment: Terrific! Solved my problem since it uses *global* hooks, ie. it receives Keyboard and Mouse event performed in any application.

Comment: Seems easier than Johannes Rossel's solution. Thanks to both of you and plus 1 to both.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309.aspx) function to react system-wide to hotkeys. However, I wouldn't advise you to use something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> which has a meaning in many applications.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a managed way to do that. At an API level you can register system-wide hooks or global hotkeys.

Writing a keylogger? :-)